# Android Default selection in spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I've seen examples of this used but I am unsure of how I should implement this in my code. Basically I want the default position to be the rowID of the previously selected item. At the moment when viewing the spinner again, it automatically selects the first item and the user has to change it every time which is not ideal.

I have seen examples of using a for loop but when I tried this the spinner didn't populate at all. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You want the previously selected item to be the default item next time the Spinner is used, is that it?

Comment: Yep, the previously selected item is stored in the database.

Comment: I have something similar - my DB is full of IPs. The last used IP is simply readded (with `update(...)`) with a new timestamp and then when I query the DB the results are sorted by timestamp, so that allows me to easily ensure that the most recent IP is the default selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an [`OnItemSelectedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) listener to the Spinner to save the current selected item's position. Then you can call `spinner.setSelection(position);` to restore the spinner to the selected position. And you should only need to do this is you want the selected item to preserve state over multiple app sessions. You will also need to save the selected item using SharedPreferences.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long row) {
        mSelectedPosition = pos;
        mSelectedItem = mItems.get(pos);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it not possible just to set the default position as the value of the foreign key in the database? the fkey stores the ID and thus should be the correct position?

Comment: If the id will always be the same position in the list then that should work.

Answer (score 0):

"At the moment when viewing the spinner again, it automatically selects the first item"
The previously selected item should be selected by the spinner, so make sure you ain't repopulate your spinner every time.